# Akka-stream filter out particular event from Cassandra

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-persistence, akka-persistent-fsm

I currently have an event sourced service supported by Akka and Cassandra. This is a bidding system called AuctionService and at some point I need to retrieve the last bid event called `BiddenOnLot`. For that I use `akka-persistence-query`.

Here is my current code:

```
        // obtain read journal by plugin id
        val readJournal = PersistenceQuery(context.system).readJournalFor[CassandraReadJournal](
          "cassandra-query-journal")

        // issue query to journal
        val source: Source[EventEnvelope, NotUsed] = readJournal.eventsByPersistenceId(self.path.name.toString, 0, Long.MaxValue)

        // materialize stream, consuming events
        implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

        source.runForeach(envelope ⇒ {
          if (envelope.event.isInstanceOf[BiddenOnLot]) {
            val biddenOnLot = envelope.event.asInstanceOf[BiddenOnLot]
            if (biddenOnLot.paddleId == paddleId) {
               // TODO: get last bid event by paddle id
            }
          }
        })
```

So far I loop through all events and can determine its type. But I'm really struggling to isolate the last bid event and be able to use it asynchronously. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using pattern matching to deconstruct emitted `EventEnvelope` and map it the event you want:

```
source.map {
    case EventEnvelope(_, _, _, bidenOnLot: BidenOnLot) if bidenOnLot.paddleId == paddleId => bidenOnLot
}.runForeach(println)
```